# PHP switch() skipping breaks to apply extra logic

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a flag that when passed to a switch statement needs different logic applied to it, three of the cases apply the same logic apart from one of those cases (out of the three) has an extra step.

Is this syntactically correct?

```
switch($foo)
{
 case 1:
      //do something
      break;
 case 2:
      //do step 1 
 case 3:
 case 4:
      //do step 2
      break;
}
```

Comment: here,case 2 , 3 and 4 will apply in same logic.

Comment: @Milap case 2 will add extra code that 3 and 4 don't run.

Comment: @Milap : not quite. 2 will apply for step 1 AND 2; and 3,4 while only apply step 2

Comment: Why isn't this technique used more often? I couldn't find examples online anywhere.

Comment: @AnthonyStansbridge Google for 'switch fallthrough' and you'll find a few. I use it quite often.

Comment: @AnthonyStansbridge its stated on the docs :) http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @Rufinus Indeed, I was aware of fallthrough with case 3 and case 4. I really wanted to know whether it was good practise / safe to apply logic between the fallthroughs. That and I didn't know what the actual term for it was, Googling 'php switch break skipping' wasn't very helpful! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is syntactically correct and will do what you've said in the comments.